# Sorting an array in Javascript based on predefined order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array:

```
var homes = [{
    "h_id": "3",
    "city": "Dallas",
    "state": "TX",
    "zip": "75201",
    "price": "162500"
}, {
    "h_id": "4",
    "city": "Bevery Hills",
    "state": "CA",
    "zip": "90210",
    "price": "319250"
}, {
    "h_id": "5",
    "city": "New York",
    "state": "NY",
    "zip": "00010",
    "price": "962500"
}];
```

And would like to sort it based on the following order

```
cities = ['New York', 'Dallas', 'Bevery Hills']
```

What's the best way to achieve it?

Comment: How about `Array.prototype.sort()`? Have you checked it already?

Comment: @diziaq done. cheers!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a standard method `Array.prototype.sort()` available.

Notice that the `sort` method does sorting in place, so internals of `homes` are going to change.

```
homes.sort(function (a,b){
  return cities.indexOf(a.city) - cities.indexOf(b.city)
});
```

If you need to keep the initial array unchanged, just make a shallow copy (`homes.slice(0)`) of it and sort the copy:

```
const sortedHomes = homes.slice(0).sort(function (a,b){
  return cities.indexOf(a.city) - cities.indexOf(b.city)
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you can use `indexOf` on `cities` to look up the final index of any home object, you can do it more efficiently than `Array.prototype.sort`:

```
var sortedHomes = new Array(cities.length);

homes.forEach(function (home) {
    var sortedIndex = cities.indexOf(home.city);
    sortedHomes[sortedIndex] = home;
});
```

<sup>(This is still O(nm) city name comparisons, time proportional to the product of the number of cities and the number of homes – an improvement over O(nm log n), but still potentially not good with a large number of cities. You can make it O(n) by flipping `cities` into a hashmap.)</sup>

If multiple homes can share the same city and `cities` doesn’t contain duplicate entries (seems the most likely situation if this is the case), you can group the homes by city and combine the result as specified by `cities`:

```
var homesByCity = {};

homes.forEach(function (home) {
    var cityHomes = homesByCity[home.city];

    if (cityHomes) {
        cityHomes.push(home);
    } else {
        cityHomes = homesByCity[home.city] = [home];
    }
});

var sortedHomes = [];

cities.forEach(function (city) {
    (homesByCity[city] || []).forEach(sortedHomes.push, sortedHomes);
});
```

<sup>(The approach is O(n) on the number of cities.)</sup>

Comment: What about the case where `homes` contains several objects in the same city?

Comment: They return in the same order they were in the original array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: @ghybs: The answer for that, if necessary, depends on the format of `cities`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest some functional programming to solve this. The snippet below should get you the result you are looking for.

```
var sorted = cities.map(function(city) {
    return homes.filter(function(home) {
        return home.city === city;
    });
});
```

First, map over the `cities` array to create a new array based on it. Second, for each city, find the corresponding item in the `homes` array and add that to the correct position in the `sorted` array.

Comment: Would that create an array of arrays of objects?

Comment: No, it gives you an array of objects that match the ones in `homes` but sorted in the order you asked for.